# What's a short film title where a guy looped inside a house repeated by death from a monster

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I'm excited to try to find a Sci-Fi short film which starts as a normal slice of life short, but ends up completely Sci-Fi.

It was shot on a camera with some CGI added in a few places, not complete 3D. It was only a few years ago, something between 2015-2020.

A guy wakes up or does something, if I'm not wrong, inside his own house, goes with a normal life routine, then standing in his kitchen (it seems to be it was a kitchen) he realises that something is wrong with sounds coming from the corridor or outside the apartment behind the door, I don't remember exactly. But for sure he follows the interest and encounters either an alien or some monster which eats him. This triggers a new loop cycle of him waking up and the loop continues somewhere from kitchen. Then the story becomes really weird because of getting used to the monster attack thus him experimenting with some alternative moves. It could be not a loop, but just a quick insight into the future or sort of, but somehow he finds his way through it and by exiting through the door finds himself in a huge hangar or something alike and that his apartment was an experimental room with some 3-digit number and the experimenters wearing antibacterial pinky costumes kill him to repeat the experiment.

It was clearly a short film, not a full-length movie. And it started as a horror, but ends up as a comedy. I might be mixing up few moments from two different short films though, but that's what I remember. And unfortunately searching through the web or youtube did not give me results.

---

UPDATE (comments) 27.11.22:

@Pete:
*Doctor Who* episode "Heaven Sent" - that’s a nice one, I should watch it. Thank you for the recommendation. But it’s not the one and let me add few exceptional things I remember about the short film:

- It's really less than half an hour, in perception something around 15-20 min max
- It's more of a modern life, just an ordinary house, ordinary apartment, not a castle, not a spaceship, just a home
- The character never leaves the apartment until the very end of the film, and when he does, he gets killed (or hibernated with a poison?) by experimenters
- The monster is quite abstract in the beginning, I do not remember the whole body being shown at all, maybe just a face full of sharp teeth as it seems
- The beginning starts with slow camera in darkness or some corners as a stadard technique used in most horrors
- I might be mistaken by the pink color of costumes, but there were definitely some characters entering and cleaning up the apartment between experiments, I just don't remember if it was shown explicitly or you may have guessed from the plot.
- The very final shot of it shows this room as a container in some bigger space with a red number on it.

@Valorum
*Edge of Tomorrow* is a good movie, the concept is similar but missing in the few points: 1) it's full-length while I'm looking for a short one, 2) the main character of the short film never leaves the room and when he finally does, he gets killed, 3) there are no famous actors in it

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?  Was it live-action or animated?

Comment: Hi @DavidW, cinematographically shot on a camera with some CGI added in a few places. It was only a few years ago, something between 2015-2020

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Landon Dies](https://crypttv.fandom.com/wiki/Landon_Dies)* by CryptTV

> Landon goes about his day again and again, only to realize after dying one too many times that something more sinister is at work.

....

> Landon wakes up that morning and puts his clothes on for the day, having a rather humorous mishap when he gets out of his bed. He goes in to brush his teeth, but the faucets are not working. He checks the pipes, and hears a strange creaking sound. He slowly exits the bathroom and looks around the hall, only to find that the door to the attic is wide open. When he turns back to the living room, there is a strange hunched-over creature in a yellow cloak. The monster slowly turns to face Landon, and a pair of ghostly-white arms suddenly emerges from the hood. Terrified, Landon runs back into his bathroom and locks the door behind him. Inside the bathroom, he hears a strange voice whispering to him. The voice says that he is a friend, and he can help Landon. Landon tentatively opens the shower curtain, but there is nothing in the shower. Suddenly, the water in the bathtub and sink turns on, and Landon, now spooked enough to run, turns around and runs into a knife. He looks up, sees the creature from before, and he is pulled into the creature's hood.
>
> The next morning, Landon wakes up to start his day, and, after a humorous mishap getting out of bed, puts his clothes on and goes into the kitchen. However, when he opens the refrigerator, he finds out that it's completely empty. He goes to open the blinds instead, only to see that the bird on the telephone lines outside has been frozen in place. As he looks out the window, the monster from before suddenly reaches out and bends his neck all the way backwards.
>
> A montage plays of Landon waking up again and again and again, only to be killed by the monster each time with a different method -- severe burns, stabbing, blunt force, and even decapitation.

### Full Film

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please gives some details of this film and explain how it matches the question.

Comment: I added a quick summary from a wiki, and a link to what looks like an official posting of the film.

Comment: Oh sorry for insufficient answer. You see, for past 2 hours I was just looking for this short film. During my search I found this discussion left without answer. When I finally found this, I made fast acc, posted title and threw phone away. I hope I managed to help at least.

Comment: @GruzjaGaming thank you thank you thank you ! This is exactly the short film I wal looking for! Indeed was a test of my memory how it mixed up many horrors and comedy horrors into a single blended thing :) Pink and red color probably from the South Korean "The Squid Game" and mistakenly remembered sharp nails on hands as teeth in a jaw. I also forgot the main concept of plural similar containers for monsters and that it's actually feeding time, not a scientific experiment :) Interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the Doctor Who episode [Heaven Sent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven_Sent_(Doctor_Who)).

> The Twelfth Doctor is teleported into a glass chamber within an empty castle in the sea. He is pursued by a cloaked veiled figure,[N 1] which evokes the Doctor’s childhood fears. When the figure corners the Doctor, he admits he is afraid to die. The figure halts and the castle reconfigures itself.

> He takes advantage of the figure's slow reaction time to explore the castle, finding several strange remnants of his predecessors, such as dry replacement clothes, a skull connected to the transportation chamber, and the word "bird" written in dust. The Doctor investigates clues left in the castle, directing him to find Room 12.

> Inside Room 12, the Doctor discovers a wall of Azbantium, a mineral harder than diamond, behind which he theorises the TARDIS to be.

> Revitalised by a vision of his dead companion, Clara, the Doctor punches the wall while reciting the fable. The figure mortally injures the Doctor, disabling his regeneration. He crawls back to the teleportation chamber, and burns his body as a catalyst to restart the teleport, aware that due to the resetting rooms, a copy of himself is inside. He then falls to the ground, writes "bird" in the dust, and disintegrates, reduced to the skull which the Doctor had seen earlier. A new Doctor appears, starting the cycle anew.

> After many more cycles,[N 2] the Doctor finally breaks through the wall.

Quite a lot matches your memory. The time period is right - first broadcast 2015. It has the plot of a man being repeatedly killed by a monster, and the man then re-created, and the cycle continues. He learns through the various iterations of the loop, and eventually escapes.

The ending doesn't quite match. When he escapes he isn't killed by people wearing antibacterial pinky costumes.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very good match

Comment: In what way?  The central plot matches: a man caught in a loop in which he is killed by a monster, and then the loop starts again. The date is right.  Yes, there are a few things that don't match, but the OP admits to a faulty memory and could be conflating other films.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head. Although your guess has a man caught in a timeloop attacked by a monster, you could say the same about a lot of films and shows; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_featuring_time_loops

Comment: Name two.  Not just "time loop", but specifically  killed by a monster and recreated.  At least one of them should be from the correct period.

Comment: Edge of Tomorrow and Koko-di Koko-da seem equally likely to be the right answer (e.g. not)

Comment: I disagree with Valorum. If nothing else, Edge of Tomorrow has a completely different structure to the time looping. No idea on *Koko-di Koko-da*.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the ideas, I've added updates to all comments. Thank you for brainstorming on it!

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Unsurprisingly, none of them were the right answer.